# Tell tsc not to compile references

Tags: typescript, reference

I have the following file structure:

```
- extensions
    - module A
      - src
        - A.ts
    - module B
      - src
        - B.ts
```

I have already compiled B.ts and I have `<reference path="../module B/src/B.ts" />` in A.ts. When A.ts is compiled with `outDir` specified the compiler will also compile B.ts, which in my case is not wanted. If I use `--noResolve` flag the output will be just resulting A.js from A.ts but the compiler will throw errors at be cause the referenced type from B.ts is not found.

Is there any way to tell tsc not to compile references but still check the types (without using .d.ts files)?

Comment: maybe if you use the ES6 import statement, i.e. `import Clazz from file` you don't have this problem any more

Comment: you could set the option to emit d.ts files, then you can simply reference those instead of the source .ts files.

Comment: `(without using .d.ts files)` <-- Why not?  This is what they were designed for.

Comment: @Pace Because it feels a bit dumb to have to generate declaration files for source code I have but I guess that has to do then for now.